# Is there a way to edit an existing nautilus (file manager) bookmark?

Tags: linux, bookmarks, nautilus, webdav

Is there a way to edit an existing [nautilus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nautilus_(file_manager)) (fie manager) bookmark?

Invoke from Linux command line:

```
$ nautilus
```

Activate connection editor:

```
File>Connect To Server...>
```

Complete entries in the pop up:

```
Service Type: [WebDAV (HTTP)]
Server: [localhost]
Port: [8001]
Folder [webdav]
Username: [test]
[x] Add bookmark
Bookmark name: [/dav]
<Connect>
```

Then in the left column of the main window the new connection and bookmark exist:

```
Places
-------------------
ausername
Desktop
File System
Network
WebDAV on localhost
Trash
--------------------
/dav
```

Right click on "/dav" pop up menu:

```
Open
Open in New Tab
Open in New Window
------------------
Remove
Rename...
```

There is no option for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in Ubuntu, there doesn't seem to be an option to edit the fancy stuff, just the server and the name used in the menu (there is an "edit bookmark" entry in the bookmark menu, but I'm sure that you found that).

The actual details are stored in a text file `~/.gtk-bookmarks`, so it should be reasonably easy to edit the file.

Perhaps you would like to file a bug either for your distro or direct with [Gnome](http://live.gnome.org/Nautilus).

Answer (score 16):

Neal's answer isn't applicable for the current combination of Ubuntu 16.04 and gtk3.
The details are stored in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.